# docker load - unexpected EOF

Tags: docker

The deployment process of some test environment requires using `docker save`, sending the file over, then using `docker load` to materialize the docker image on the other end.

Today this started happening for some reason:

```
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the image upload was not successful, and the file was cut short, so it literally had an unexpected `EOF`. (duh)

Using `md5sum` or `ls` to compare the files would have helped me spot this error much sooner.

Shoutout to [this google result](https://fedidat.com/330-docker-save-error-processing-tar-files/) which stated the same.